# After what version of rspec was the support for reading .rspec added

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to add "--require spec_helper" to .rspec file based on a suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097049/371572

I tried to create .rspec file in the root of the webapp and added the above line but it doesn't seem to work. Neither does added to spec/spec.opts
I realized that the version of rspec we are using is 1.3.2 and rspec-rails version of 1.3.4. So I was wondering if there is a support for reading .rspec file in this version. How do I look up or verify that.

P.S. I run specs using bundle exec rake spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.rspec` file has always been supported in RSpec 2 (the oldest entry in [its history](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Changelog.md), for 2.0.0.beta.22, references it, and it was originally added in [fd0398e](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/fd0398e9e8e61c69cf95aa9e41b440d0d622a095) as `.rspecrc` and renamed to `.rspec` in [beaf23b](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/beaf23b9bc519c5b9dba0d42fafcbd158159a599)). It has never been supported in RSpec 1.

That said, RSpec 1.x is massively old. I’d strongly suggest you attempt to migrate to RSpec 2 (which came out nearly 3 years ago).